# Enable/Disable button using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

I need to enable/disable button if both checkboxes are checked. I want to do in knockout.js. I am still a beginner. I have found an example [enable/disable button using checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/dxf856jy/) but that is doing for 1 checkbox. In my scenario, i have two checkboxes and they both should be checked to enable the button. If any of the checkbox is not checked then the button should be disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myBoolean" />
<button data-bind="enable: myBoolean">My Button</button>

ko.applyBindings({ myBoolean: ko.observable(true) });
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. add another observable for the other checkbox
2. add a [computed observable](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for the button, which returns true only when both checkboxes are checked (observables are true)

```js
var test = { 
  myBoolean1: ko.observable(false),
  myBoolean2: ko.observable(false)
};
test.myComputed = ko.computed(function() { return test.myBoolean1() && test.myBoolean2() });

ko.applyBindings(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myBoolean1" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myBoolean2" />
<button data-bind="enable: myComputed">My Button</button>
```

Comment: thanks Philip thats exactly what i wanted. Is there a way we can check if myBoolean1 or myBoolean2 exist. There might be a case where there will be only 1 checkbox

Comment: For that case you should create an object and html just like you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS only. Unless you need to support IE10 or lower.

```css
button {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
  background-color: white;
}

#firstCheckbox:checked+#secondCheckbox:checked+button {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="firstCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="secondCheckbox">
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way we can do that in Knockout.js?